# Can't connect mssql with PHP under mac Yosemite

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, freetds

I'm using PHP 5.5 under Mac Yosemite, the default php with this SO. i'm trying to connect to MSSQL DB server but it's imposible with a lot of alternatives.

I tried to install freetds and the command works but when i tried with PHP...its look he is trying to load but the connection close. My code on PHP is like this:

```
$server = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' ;
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$DB = "";

$link = mssql_connect($server, $user, $pass) ;

if(!$link){
    die('Something goes wrong');
}
```

I look into php info and it's enabled:
[php info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKyMH.png)

¿Someone knows what is the best alternative to connect to mssql db and works?

Comment: *mssql, php, osx: let's mix it!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now it's working with these lines:

```
try {
    $hostname = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX';
    $port = 1433;
    $dbname = "YOUR_DB";
    $username = "YOUR_USERNAME";
    $pw = "YOUR_PASS";
    $dbh = new PDO ("dblib:host=$hostname:$port;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}
```

First you have to install [PDO_DBLIB](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php) in your system.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`mssql_get_last_message()`](http://docs.php.net/function.mssql-get-last-message) to find out what the error is, then, fix the problem.

```
$server = 'XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' ;
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$DB = "";

$link = mssql_connect($server, $user, $pass) ;

echo mssql_get_last_message();
echo mssql_min_error_severity();
die();
```

Comment: @AlbertoIglesias Try it like it is now, just edited some stuff.

Comment: That don't throw anything, i have debug mode on and throw this line Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server...